# txt file into pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a `txt` file where values are randomly separated, sometimes there is a single space, and sometimes there are many. I am importing the file into pandas with `pd.read_csv`, but I get only one column in my DataFrame.  How can I define the sep parameter to read the values properly?

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need to differentiate between one or more spaces?
If so, maybe you can make use of a regular expression separator as listed in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Something like this:

```
pd.read_csv(... sep='\s+', ...)
```

Also, consider adding the parameter `delim_whitespace` as such:

```
pd.read_csv(..., delim_whitespace=True, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I've found some other way. I will try with read_fwf. I think I will be able to cover most of the values with that instead of read_csv